# jquery post problem with callback

Tags: jquery

I can't get any callback data:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#JqPostForm").submit(function(){
        jQuery.post("index.php?option=comp&task=sendemail", jQuery("#JqPostForm").serialize(),

        function(data){
        alert('ok');
            if(data.email_check == 'invalid'){

                    jQuery("#message_post").html("<div class='errorMessage'>Sorry " + data.name + ", " + data.email + " is NOT a valid e-mail address. Try again.</div>");
            } else {
                jQuery("#message_post").html("<div class='successMessage'>" + data.email + " is a valid e-mail address. Thank you, " + data.name + ".</div>");
                }
        }, "json");

        return false;

});
});
</script>
```

The echo in php function is: `echo json_encode($return_arr);` which is: `{"email_check":"invalid","name":null,"email":null}`

but can't get it working i'm developing on localhost and firefox

Comment: From the jQuery site: "If a request with jQuery.post() returns an error code, it will fail silently unless the script has also called the global .ajaxError()  method. " Have you called global .ajaxError() ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the server sends the appropriate content type:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: Place it at the top of your PHP file

Comment: I'm sending it to joomla function might that be a problem?

Comment: You need to make sure that json is actually returned. Use a tool like Fiddler to test the response of the server. Firebug will also help.

Comment: it looks like it sending in text/html not json? fiddler shows content type  text/html

Comment: I've changed it to json in joomla but still no success

Comment: Ok I've found a solution first of use index2.php or send in raw format the only function is returned set headers to json

Comment: // Get the document object.
 $document =& JFactory::getDocument();
 // Set the MIME type for JSON output.
 $document->setMimeEncoding( 'application/json' );